# Ruby shoes gui toolkit. How was this made?

Tags: ruby, shoes

I've been building a lot of projects over the last few months using Ruby. Every project has been some sort of game that outputs to the command line. The shoes gui toolkit says it is written in Ruby. My question is how would you go about writing a script in ruby that would open a little dialog box with a button, without some sort of toolkit like Shoes. I'd like to know whats going on behind the scenes of this short piece of Shoe's code that brings up a window with a few buttons in it.

```
Shoes.app {
        background white
        stack(margin: 8) {
          button "A bed of clams"
          button "A coalition of cheetahs"
          button "A gulp of swallows"
        }
      }
```

I have been under the assumption things like this could only be done with JS/HTML/CSS.

Comment: there are lots of gui toolkits. see [List_of_platform-independent_GUI_libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_platform-independent_GUI_libraries) or [List_of_widget_toolkits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits)

Comment: Thank you but im more interested in knowing how something like a button would be written in ruby, the code behind the toolkits methods

Comment: All of the code for Shoes is [on GitHub](http://shoesrb.com/contribute/).